# Optional cast to protocol's associated type is failing (returning nil)

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

I have a protocol in my open source library ([link in-case code samples aren't enough](https://github.com/simonmitchell/rocc/tree/feature/ptp_ip_cameraprotocol_implementation)).

Said protocol has two associated types, one for a function "send" type, and one for a "return type" defined like so:

```
/// A protocol which can be adopted to define a function that can be performed on any given camera
public protocol CameraFunction {

    /// An associated type which is taken as an input when calling this function on a `Camera` instance
    associatedtype SendType

    /// An associated type which is returned from the camera when calling this function on the `Camera`
    associatedtype ReturnType

    /// The enum representation of this given function
    var function: _CameraFunction { get }
}
```

In a function implementation (`performFunction` declared on another protocol):

```
func performFunction<T>(_ function: T, payload: T.SendType?, callback: @escaping ((Error?, T.ReturnType?) -> Void)) where T : CameraFunction {

        switch function.function {
        case .getEvent:
            let packet = Packet.commandRequestPacket(code: .getAllDevicePropData, arguments: [0], transactionId: ptpIPClient?.getNextTransactionId() ?? 0)
            ptpIPClient?.awaitDataFor(transactionId: packet.transactionId, callback: { (dataResult) in

                switch dataResult {
                case .success(let data):
                    guard let numberOfProperties = data.data[qWord: 0] else { return }
                    var offset: UInt = UInt(MemoryLayout<QWord>.size)
                    var properties: [PTPDeviceProperty] = []
                    for _ in 0..<numberOfProperties {
                        guard let property = data.data.getDeviceProperty(at: offset) else { break }
                        properties.append(property)
                        offset += property.length
                    }
                    let event = CameraEvent(sonyDeviceProperties: properties)
                    callback(nil, event as? T.ReturnType)
                case .failure(let error):
                    callback(error, nil)
                }
            })
            ptpIPClient?.sendCommandRequestPacket(packet, callback: nil)
```

I create a `CameraEvent` object and attempt to downcast (unsure if that's the correct terminology) to `T.ReturnType`. At the point that is called, `event` is `non-nil`, however casting it to `T.ReturnType` gives a `nil` result even though it should match!

`Event.get` (.getEvent) is defined like so:

```
/// Functions for interacting with the event API on the camera
public struct Event: CameraFunction {

    public var function: _CameraFunction

    public typealias SendType = Bool

    public typealias ReturnType = CameraEvent

    /// Gets the current event
    public static let get = Event(function: .getEvent)
}
```

It's important to note as well that another implementation of the second protocol I talk about (The one defining the `performFunction` function) successfully does very similar logic and I don't get nil back! There must be something I'm doing wrong here, but I have no idea what it could be!

Screenshots in case that helps!

#### Calling the protocol's function

[image: Calling the protocol function]

#### Implementation of the protocol's function

[image: Implementation of the protocol function]

Comment: Actually I’m surprised that the expression `event as? T.ReturnType` compiles in the first place.

Comment: I know right @matt! Generics are powerful and awesome! Pretty sure I’m using them a bit irresponsibly, but this is the second implementation of the other protocol (`Camera`) to use this and the other one has been fine since January!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was... just the debugger being a pile of rubbish! Decided to add in a `print` statement to make absolutely sure it was `nil`. Turns out that wasn't the case! Prints fine, but `lldb` seems to think it's nil for whatever reason.